# How to make MutationObserver also report child nodes of mutated nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

Is it possible, and how, to get reports from a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for each child node (not just immediate children) of a mutated node?

Take a look at the following snippet:

```js
    ($ => {
        $(() => {
            var $body = $(document.body).html('');

            (new MutationObserver(function (records) {
                for (var record of records) {
                    console.log('----------');

                    for (var node of record.addedNodes) {
                        if (node instanceof Element) {
                            console.log('addition', node.tagName, node.childNodes.length);
                        }
                    }
                    for (var node of record.removedNodes) {
                        if (node instanceof Element) {
                            console.log('removal', node.tagName, node.childNodes.length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })).observe(document.body, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });

            $body.append('<a/>');
            $body.find('a').wrap('<span/>');
            $body.append('<div><b/></div>');
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First I remove everything from the body for clarity. Then I attach a `MutationObserver` that will report additions and removals and also report the child nodes count.

As you can see I append an `<a/>` element to the body and then simply wrap it in a `<span/>`. After that I append a `<b/>` element inside a `<div/>` element. If you take a look at the console you'll probably see the following output:

```
----------
addition A 0
----------
addition SPAN 1
----------
removal A 0
----------
addition A 0
----------
addition DIV 1
```

So, the first append is properly reported with 0 child nodes.

Then, during the `wrap()` call, a new `<span/>` element is added, the `<a/>` element is removed and then added back (this time inside the span). Everything is reported properly, except for the fact that (at the time of reporting) one would expect the `<span/>` element to be empty, yet it already has a child node - the wrapped `<a/>`.

This is actually per the specs where it is specified that such mutations are queued and then fired *asynchronously*, even though the execution of the callback is *synchronous*. This is intentional as the listeners would otherwise be bombarded with events and significantly damage performance.

Additionally, the final addition reports the added `<div/>` element (already including 1 child node), but not its child `<b/>` element.

This is, again, probably intentional as firing an addition mutation for *every single* node essentially added to the DOM would be a performance nightmare.

As part of a plugin I am working on I need to "know" about each final element node added or removed to and from the DOM, even if it is part of a sub-tree.

My original solution was to just traverse all child nodes when a node is added / removed and treat them as added / removed as well. Unfortunately that is not viable since the state of the DOM has already changed when the listener is invoked as demonstrated by `addition SPAN 1`.

So, do you know of any "feature" or approach that would allow me to report / determine, at least in the context of my code, that those child nodes have too been added to the node along with their parent?

Comment: 1. It is a valid shortcut markup for jQuery, it is automatically added as a regular element. 2. I know they are not reported, that's my question, how to report them. This approach won't work as `getElementsByTagName('*')` might, for example, return nodes added in the future, though the listener would expect the node to be empty. See my `addition SPAN 1` example.

Comment: MO can't do what you want by design. Use the deprecated DOM mutation events for synchronous operation.

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestion.